# Unity: GameObject repeated instantiation issue

Tags: c#, debugging, unity-game-engine, infinite-loop, instantiation

I am trying to instantiate a zombie prefab every time I call NewSpawn(), which is when reSpawn variable becomes 'true'(through inspector). However, once I instantiate one zombie it does an infinite loop of clones of the zombie. [Making clones of clones of clones] How do I limit it to one zombie instantiation per method call? (I'd like to make 10 zombies, not 10,000. 
Thank you!
[image: Errors for Zombie Navigation and instantiation]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Zombie : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject zombiePrefab;
    public Transform zombieSpawnPoint;
    private Transform[] spawnPositions;
    public bool reSpawn = false;
    private bool lastToggle = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        spawnPositions = zombieSpawnPoint.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
    }

    private void NewSpawn()   //spawn location of newZombie
    {
        Instantiate(zombiePrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        int i = Random.Range(1, spawnPositions.Length);
        transform.position = spawnPositions[i].transform.position;

    }


    void Update () { //T-toggle
        if (reSpawn != lastToggle)
        {
            NewSpawn();
            reSpawn = false;
        }
        else
            lastToggle = reSpawn;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call `NewSpawn()` in your button click event instead of setting `reSpawn` to true.

Besides that this doesn't make any sense:

```
else
{
   lastToggle = reSpawn;
}
```

They are already equal.

Comment: Ok, figured it out, it's because the prefab that was being instantiated had the zombie script. When I removed it, it single-instantiated. However, I have run into the problem where the zombie prefab doesn't accept the scene's Player Transform, and when I put the Player prefab they don't run towards the player anymore. How do I get the zombies to run towards the zombie with a Player Prefab and not the Player Scene's?

Comment: @BenSmith That's a whole different topic. Consider making a new question for that. I will try to help you out there.